# ¿Cómo puedo ocultar la hora en un datetimepicker? tempus dominus

Tags: jquery

¿Cómo puedo ocultar la hora y que solo muestre la fecha?, estoy utilizando la librería de tempus dominus y el selector lleva abajo para seleccionar la hora.

He probado con esto pero sigue apareciendo:

```
window.datetimepicker1 = $('.fecha').tempusDominus({
   localization: {
     format: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontré en la documentación el componente display que regulas todas las opciones del calendario.

```js
window.datetimepicker1 = $('.fecha').tempusDominus({

display: {
 components: {
        calendar: true,
        date: true,
        month: true,
        year: true,
        decades: true,
        clock: false,
        hours: false,
        minutes: false,
        seconds: false,
        
      },
 }
});
```

```html
<div class="mb-3">      
        <label  class="form-label">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
    <input th:field="${participanteModifica.fechaS}" type="text" class="fecha" />
    </div>
```